# C++ how to delete a structure?

Tags: c++, structure

Structure I created:

```
   struct VideoSample
  { 
      const unsigned char * buffer;
      int len;
  };

   VideoSample * newVideoSample = new VideoSample;
   newVideoSample->buffer = buf;
   newVideoSample->len = size;

       //...
```

How now to delete it now?

Comment: Who owns the *buffer*?  Odds are non-zero that you need a destructor as well.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
delete newVideSample;
```

This won't free any memory you allocated to `newVideoSample->buffer` though - you have to free it explicitly before deleting.

```
//Free newVideSample->buffer if it was allocated using malloc
free((void*)(newVideSample->buffer));

//if it was created with new, use `delete` to free it
delete newVideSample->buffer;

//Now you can safely delete without leaking any memory
delete newVideSample;
```

Normally this kind of freeing is written in the [destructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_science%29) of the class so that it'll be called automatically when you `delete` the dynamically created object.

Thanks @steve for mentioning it :)

Comment: fives me C2664 on free(newVideSample->buffer); line. something like  it cannot convert const unsigned char into void *

Comment: This deserves a -1 - for use of `free` without knowing where the memory came from, and for not recommending this be done in destructor if pointer is set. Not downvoting, because no other answer even mentions this.

Comment: @Kabumbus I thought casting will happen automatically - cast buffer to (void*) and you'll be good to go. Also, use free/delete on the `buffer` only if you allocated it - if, as shown in the question, the buffer was initialized with a pointer that was already allocated (and used even after newVideSample is deleted), you need not and should not free/delete it

Comment: most likely it should be delete [] for the buffer. but once again don't know.

Answer (score 8):

```
delete newVideoSample;
```

But if the `new` and `delete` are in the same context, you're probably better off skipping them and just creating it on the stack instead:

```
VideoSample newVideoSample = {buf, size};
```

In that case, no cleanup is necessary.

Comment: Yes by default there is no need to "new" or "delete" objects. Use it only if you really know why you need it.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `delete` keyword:

```
delete newVideoSample;
```

Answer (score 3):

`delete newVideoSample;`

However, consider using a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) that will release the memory automatically, for example:

```
std::auto_ptr<VideoSample> newVideoSample(new VideoSample);
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++ a structure is the exact same as a class except everything is public by default, where a class is private by default. So a structure can have a destructor and is freed with delete.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, you just use `delete`:

```
delete newVideoSample;
```

Answer (score 2):

`delete newVideoSample` .
In C++ `struct` is the same as `class` but with default public fields.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`delete`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete/)

```
VideoSample * newVideoSample = new VideoSample;
//.. stuffs

delete newVideoSample;
```

There is also an [overload](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete%5b%5d/) i.e `delete[]`

```
VideoSample * newVideoSample = new VideoSample[n];
//.. stuffs

delete [] newVideoSample;
```

---

In Modern C++ it is always recommended to use smart pointers. You may want to use `boost::shared_ptr<T>` from the boost library.

Answer (score 2):

If you intended VideoSample to free its `buffer` member then VideoSample is a fragile class.  It has no way of knowing whether `buf` was created in the heap using `new[]` or `malloc`, or is the address of a variable on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You created an object of `Videosample` , so you just need to use use delete..

```
VideoSample * newVideoSample = new VideoSample;
delete newVideoSample;
```

Answer (score 1):

To Allocate ->
    VideoSample * newVideoSample = new VideoSample;

To Delete ->
    delete newVideoSample;

If you deleting the object in the same context, you better just allocate it on the stack.
If you deleting it outside the context don't forget to pass a reference.

And most important, don't delete if your about to exit process, it's pointless :P

Comment: "don't delete if your about to exit process, it's pointless" **No.** Why was this at +2? At the very least, to explicitly `delete` is self-documenting and polite. More so, what if the OS omits to delete the object or one of _its_ resources? Also it ensures you avoid false positives in memory-leak analysers, etc. Really, `delete`ing isn't difficult, so just do it always. If you start excusing omission in situations that [Dr Evil fingers] """shouldn't""" matter, you're asking for trouble when you forget to `delete` in a situation where it  _really does_. http://stackoverflow.com/q/677812/2757035