# RECT struct allocate and delete

Tags: delete-operator

If i do like that, it will delete only pointer to struct, or completely free all allocated memory without any leaks?

```
RECT* winrect = new RECT;
winrect->top = 0;
winrect->left = 0;
winrect->right = wnd_width * glb_scale;
winrect->bottom = wnd_height * glb_scale;

delete winrect;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134323/c-how-to-delete-a-structure