# Windows 7 cleans up C++ memory leaks?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, macos, memory-leaks

Just for fun I created a project that created about 5 GB of memory and did not delete it. As long as the application is running that "memory leak" is there. The second I close my application the memory within 2 seconds is back down to normal as if my program never ran. So the questions have to be asked.

Does Windows 7 clean up memory leaks from bad programs when they are done?

Do all Windows versions do this?

Will Linux and Mac OS X environments do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a reason to call delete in C++ when a program is exiting anyway?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677812/is-there-a-reason-to-call-delete-in-c-when-a-program-is-exiting-anyway)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When the program terminates, the operating system reclaims all the memory that had previously been allocated to it. Cleaning up memory leaks may be a perceived by-product of this, but the OS does not actually see it that way. It does not know that the program had been leaking memory, just that it had allocated it.

Comment: +1 This is what actually happens.The OS doesn't know the process leaked memory, it doesn't have to.It just takes back what it had given.

Answer (score 10):

Once a process in which your application runs exits, the OS reclaims all the memory allocated to the process.

This is typically true for all operating systems not just Windows 7 or Windows for that matter.

Note that, you may observe different behavior for *other* leaking resources like file handles etc, usually OS'es dont reclaim those. So, it is *usually*(Yes,there are exceptions) a good practice to make your own application clear the mess(deallocate the allocated resource) that it made instead of delegating it to the OS.

Comment: I was checking for some documents from MS but couldnt find any stating their memory management rules.

Comment: @Rohit: This is the very basis of any OS.If memory leaking applications/processes were allowed to leak memory forever,the OS would have to reboot periodically, the fact that it doesn't have to is a testimonial to the fact.

Comment: i agree on that but still there should be something on it. I think i should refer to my Operating Systems textbook of graduation days to find something.

Comment: I too had accepted this as a fact. But still when some one posts it as a question citing a reference will always be more appealing

Comment: The only resources that might (should) leak on program exit are somewhat esoteric things such as shared memory segments (which are, in general, intended to out-survive the programs that create them).  There are not many items in that category.  Things like file descriptors should be released on all the systems discussed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: But file descriptors are like dumb pointers. If they point to a temporary file, that temporary file is leaked, even thought the descriptor istelf is released.

Comment: @Rohit: It's not stated explicitly. It follows from "A process has a virtual address space". Allocations are done in this virtual address space, not in physical RAM. This virtual address space belongs to the process, therefore dies with it, and in turn that means all allocations are gone too.

Comment: @MSalters - thta's one reason why many OS provide temporary file folders that are auto-purged.  If you app is designed so that it can dribble leftover, half-eaten files when killed off, the temp folder is one place to write them.  Another choice is for the app to create its own temp folder and clean up on startup - much safer and easier than cleaning up on app close.  A prompt and reliable app shutdown AND no leftover Valgrind/temp files/whatever  is becoming very difficult and, in many cases counter-productive since the shutdown code itself has bugs and needs testing/fixing :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes (Windows 7 does reclaim all memory allocated to a program when the program exits, regardless of how it exits — under control or when crashing).
2. Yes (for any version of Windows that's recent enough to be still running).
3. Yes (Unix, Linux, Mac OS X, BSD all reclaim all memory allocated to a program when the program exits, regardless of how it exits).

A few old operating systems did not reacquire resources when a program exited.  I believe AmigaOS was one; another, I believe, was the old Mac OS (Mac OS 9 and earlier).  However, substantially all true multi-tasking systems have to reclaim memory (and resources in general) when the process to which it was allocated exits.

Answer (score 1):

Not only does the program manages memory but does the OS too. And it reclaims all the memory allocated to a program after it exist. It doesn't interfere in between the execution of the program (Other than for paging and swapping). This control over memory of the OS helps the OS from crashing from memory leaks to a point.

> Memory management is the act of managing computer memory. The
>   essential requirement of memory management is to provide ways to
>   dynamically allocate portions of memory to programs at their request,
>   and freeing it for reuse when no longer needed. This is critical to
>   the computer system.

BSD Unix normally starts reclaiming memory when the percentage of free memory drops below 5% and continues reclaiming until the free memory percentage reaches 7%

Answer (score -2):

This is not the case for all OS's, for example, I do not believe WinXP will behave this way.

Though for most modern OS's it is now the case. I believe all current versions of Linux, Windows and MacOS do this.

For windows, I'm pretty sure it was introduced in Windows Vista. At the time it was a rather exciting improvement as there were A LOT of dodgey windows applications out there that didn't manage their memory well. At the time it was a big win for windows, but it had come late to the party (as usual), as Linux and MacOS were already doing it long before.

Having said that, I'm sure you appreciate that you definitely still need to manage your memory properly within your application and not simply rely upon your OS to clean up after you. Applications need to be efficient and predictable with their memory use during their runtime as well.

Comment: i agree there was great improvement in memory management in Vista and so is in 7. But that doesnt mean XP wouldnt take back all the allocated memories. There was always VM in XP

Comment: It in fact dates back to NT 3.1. Win95 was another matter, but that codeline died with WinME, 2 decades ago.

Comment: All versions of Windows NT since 1993 (including XP) have had process-based virtual memory; Vista introduced various protection and performance improvements, but didn't change the underlying memory model. You may be thinking of the DOS-based versions of Windows (such as 95, 98 and ME) which had rather poor memory management. Thankfully, they are ancient history now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's becoming increasingly difficult to not rely upon the OS cleaning up.  Preventing a thread that is currently blocked from becoming signaled and trying to access freed memory is very difficult for user code but trivially easy for the OS.  Stopping a thread that is running on a different CPU core than the one wishing to clean up the memory in use is very difficult for user code, but easy for an OS. 'relying upon your OS to clean up' is a viable option in many designs and the alternative of 'manually' claning up is becoming ever more difficult.  Start getting used to the idea.