# If an application has memory leaks are these resolved at termination?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 cleans up C++ memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987008/windows-7-cleans-up-c-memory-leaks)

I'm discussing a case with coworkers where an exceptional case causes a Windows C++ application to exit rapidly, and the nature of our code means this seems likely to cause memory leaks.

If the application is closing down anyway, does this matter? Will leaked memory be returned to the system when the process ends?

Comment: This has 1billion dupes.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate. The answer is yes, but it's still bad.

Comment: Surely it can't have a billion duplicates, every time a duplicate is created it should be closed. Find a duplicate and mark it. And perhaps pick on the other 999,999,999 dupklicates not just mine!

Comment: @Pubby why is it bad - the whole point is it's an exception circumstance so why does it matter? For real reasons I mean, not idealistic ones.

Comment: @John because it's undefined behavior (ie won't work on every system) and your destructors won't be called.

Comment: This is a Windows-specific question so isn't it well-defined in that niche?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Will leaked memory be returned to the system when the process ends?
```

Yes system will claim back the dynamic allocated memory. Some system resources will won't be released, for example: shared memory.

Comment: good distinction between different resource types; I'm referring to 'normally' allocated memory only.

Answer (score 5):

Modern desktop operating systems like Linux, OSX and Windows all frees up allocated resources when a process exits.

On embedded systems probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when the application exits, the operating system will free resources associated with the exiting process.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocated by an application is allocated in the process memory. It's release at process termination.