# Using a variable that was defined in an if statement before

Tags: c++, object

```
int main() {
    if(i = 0) {
        myclass1 a = "Example1";
    }
    else {
        myclass2 a = "Example2";
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

I know a way to do this is by defining it outside the block but what if I have not decided what type `a` is before checking the condition of `i`?

Comment: maybe templates and/or lambda's ?

Comment: `i = 0` is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: Do `myclass1` and `myclass2` share common base class?

Comment: Move print line into if scope? I know that this is an example but if the usage is short, eventhough they are identical, copy it; Instead of using additional libraries and many cluttering tricks.

Comment: A frequent observation here on stackoverflow is: When a "simple" question is asked, some very sophisticated, tricky or elegant solutions are proposed. While this may be interesting, educating and not necessarily "wrong", I think that in many cases, it would be **far** more appropriate to ask: **What do you actually want to achieve?**. This is the question that has to be answered first, before **any** potential solution can be considered to be "good" or "bad" in the first place.

Answer (score 27):

If you are able to use [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can use the [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) in case your types haven't common base class. These classes are type-safe containers for any or specified types. An example with `std::variant` can be the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

int main() {
    bool input = false;
    std::cin >> input;

    std::variant<int, long, double, std::string> myVariant;
    if(input)
        myVariant = "Example1";
    else
        myVariant = 3.14;

    std::visit([](auto&& arg) { std::cout << arg << std::endl; }, myVariant);
}
```

Instead of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you also can use the [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) or the [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: Note: may want to use a lambda to *generate* the variant, so as to avoid default construction (not all types are default constructible after all).

Comment: @r1verside Oh that's what I don't call sarcasm ;-) (But I agree. I don't want to offend the asker, but the nature of the question makes it **very** likely that this is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ... )

Answer (score 21):

C++ is a **statically typed** language, and requires the type of variables being used in the code to be known at compile time.

There's no way to write a C++ program where a statement like `std::cout << a;` is compiled and the type of `a` is not known until run-time.

For that you need a **dynamically typed** language, like for example Python or JavaScript.

Comment: There is ``std::any`` nowadays (or ``boost::any`` before C++17). That said, I would not recommend using it without a compelling use case.

Comment: @ArneVogel: that's a specific type

Comment: -1 It's for being able to do things like this that inheritance exists.  You also don't mention that ```a``` is out of scope.

Comment: @6502: Fair enough, from a language lawyer perspective, ``std::any`` is about as static as types get. From a practical perspective, it is an enabler for a form of dynamic typing, however. C++ is a multi-paradigm language that allows "fully" static typing (e.g. using templates), inheritance polymorphism and even type erasure on unrelated types (commonly implemented using polymorphism). For instance, ``std::shared_ptr`` is able to store a type-erased deleter with few commonalities with others (i.e. copying/moving and function call (operator)).

Comment: @ArneVogel: from a practical point of view the main problem is that C++ lacks any form of run-time introspection (except for a type "name" that means very little) and this blocks the ability of compiling code that manipulates objects unless for the characteristics it knows about at compile time. It lacks even the ability of just making a copy or destroy an object because despite being a copy-based language copying and destroying is not exposed in a standard way (at run time). You can try to glue-in some tricky patch like the stateless deleter idea, but you can't go far down that path.

Answer (score 7):

You could try [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).
Assuming `myclass1` and `myclass2` "implement" a class called `myclass`, you can do something like this:

```
int main() {
    myclass*a;
    if (i=0) {
        a = new myclass1("Example1");
    } else {
        a = new myclass2("Example2");
    }
    cout<<*a<<endl;
}
```

If you want to actively use the type `myclass1` or `myclass2` later on, you can use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), but depending on your needs and what behaviour you implement in your inherited classes and your base class, thay may not be necessary.

Note I use a raw pointer here, since it's a short-lived object and it's clear the program has ended. I encourage you to read about [smart pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp) and use them appropriately to avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Beware memory leaks in some platforms persist until after a reboot, it may be needed to manually free (delete) allocated memory. More about all that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232262/memory-leak-in-c-c-forgot-to-do-free-delete).

Comment: Your answer is correct **only** if `myclass1`, and `myclass2` share a base class. As the question is written - such information is not specified, hence they must be treated as unrelated types.

Comment: That's why I explicitly state I assume myclass1 and myclass2 implement a common base class.

Comment: In that case, I will repeat myself, in a clearer fashion: your "_answer_" is nothing more than a speculation on the fact whether OPs example was complete. If it is, though, your "_answer_" is just wrong. In addition, your example is leaking memory.

Comment: OP is free to do as he likes, I merely provide a suggestion that can clearly solve his problem, as stated in the question (which I've interpreted as "how can I use a variable declaring it out of an if conditional, with two possible different types initialized inside each path of the conditional respectively?").

Comment: So myclass1 and myclass2 do have a base class myclass. And you saying I should make a new class called baseclass, if then what should baseclass be? Or you meant Baseclass is myclass?

Comment: @ViệtEngland You comment that "_So myclass1 and myclass2 do have a base class myclass._" This is important and relevant to any answers. Please **edit** your question and add this important information.

Comment: @ViệtEngland If you've already got a base class called `myclass`, then that's what you might need (I edited my example to reflect this naming). You most likely don't need two base classes for this one task I assume you need. Also, see answer from user 6502, and read relevant subjects in my links for more information that can be useful. Do ask us stuff if you get stuck!

Comment: please **stop** encouraging explicit manual dynamic allocations (raw use of `new`). We have smart pointers.

Comment: There are places for raw pointers; there is never a place for lazily not bothering to clean up after yourself.

Comment: @JackAidley While I would happily use similar short-lived programs in most (any?) modern OS, I understand some OS don't reclaim memory until after a reboot ([AmigaOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987025/2550349)). I stand corrected, but point-out that this is platform-dependant (as is compiler support).

Answer (score 7):

```
int main() {
    auto call = [](auto a) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    };

    if(i = 0)
        call(myclass1 { "Example1" });
    else 
        call(myclass2 { "Example2" });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This definitively calls for polymorphism, and optionally, if you want to have it a bit more elegant, the [factory pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Factory). The factory pattern is no magic, it just hides the `if` within a nice wrapper.

Why not another approach, such as e.g. `std::variant` which is basically a `union` in disguise? Well, it's nice if you are able to store different kinds of things, or even *any* kind (`std::any`) under the same name, but it is not very useful since you *also* want to do something meaningful with the object. If you want to do completely different, unrelated things, then you can as well have different objects scoped by the `if` blocks (and with completely different code). If, however, you want to do the same or similar things on different objects, then they (usually) need to be the same or a related type.

Different types typically do not have the same data members or the same publicly accessible member functions. So, doing the same thing on a source code level with different types typically doesn't work (except by coincidence).

But if two classes *do have* identical subsets on their interfaces, and you want to be able to do it in one or the other way interchangeably, then inheriting from a base class is the most natural and idiomatic thing to do. That's what polymorphism was invented for. Use the idiomatic thing.

(You can get the same net effect of calling functions with the same name on different, unrelated types via a template helper, and presumed that the names that you use exist, that will *just work*, but it's not nearly as good style, and it causes huge bloat by instanciating the function twice).

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to give you a practical answer that assumes you're used to doing this sort of thing in JavaScript or something and just trying to write code in C++.

First, you should understand that in C++, `cout << a`.  Can actually call a *completely different* method depending on the type of `a`.  For that reason, it doesn't make any sense to write `cout << a` when you don't know anything about that type.  In fact, you can't do anything at all with `a` unless you know enough about the type for C++ to decide which method or operator you want to invoke.

If both of your classes have an acceptable common base, then you could do something this:

```
int main() {
    base_class *pa;
    my_class1 a1;
    my_class2 a2;

    if(i = 0) {
        a1 = "Example1";
        pa = &a1;
    }
    else {
        a2 = "Example2";
        pa = &a2;
    }
    cout << *pa << endl;
}
```

Note that when you write `cout << *pa`, you are *not* necessarily calling the same method that `cout << a` would use.  In the first case you are calling a method that knows how to output all subclasses of `base_class`, while in the second case you may be calling a method that was written specifically for `myclass1` or `myclass2`.

When there is no acceptable base class, then we just don't write code like that in C++:

```
int main() {
    if(i = 0) {
        myclass1 a = "Example1";
        cout << a << endl;
    }
    else {
        myclass2 a = "Example2";
        cout << a << endl;
    }
}
```

Remember that the two methods being called in these cases can be *completely different* methods.  It's exactly like calling `cout.printClass1(a)` vs. `cout.printClass2(a)`.  C++ lets you use the same name for completely different methods when it can figure out which one you want to call based on the argument types.

JavaScript doesn't have any magic that could automatically choose between `printClass1` and `printClass2` when you write cout.callWhatever(a), and neither does C++.  In *both* languages, if you have to call completely different methods for `myclass1` vs. `myclass2`, then you write different calls.

Comment: +1 for avoiding `new` / `delete` while still getting polymorphism, unlike some other pointer-to-base-class answers.

Answer (score 3):

I had such code myself, when I was in fact trying different *variations* of the same code. Then I realized the best option would be to use a preprocessor `#if` and it solved my problem:

```
#define VARIATION 2

...

#if VARIATION == 1
    myclass1 a = "Example1";
#else
    myclass2 a = "Example2";
#endif
```

I know it probably doesn't solve yours, but at least it is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If it is this specific problem I would think that this would be much more easier

```
int main(){
    if(i == 0)          //You wrote i=0 !! silly mistake
        std::cout << myclass1("Example1");
    else
        std::cout << myclass2("Example2");
}
```

or you can choose

```
template<class T>
void foo(T out)
{
    std::cout << out;
}

int main()
{
    if( i==0 )
        foo(myclass1("ex1"));
    else
        foo(myclass2("ex2"));
}
```

else

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45754769/6459731)  is the way to go
And  I would advise against using cout here as it may not have overloads to accept your user defined class.