# What Happens To Dynamically Allocated Variables Without Handles ? (C++)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

Does instantiating classes without handles like this cause memory leaks in C++?

`new SomeClass();`

What about passing them inside methods?

`SomeMethod(new SomeClass())`

Do they get deallocated after the method's definition goes out of scope?

It does sound like a stupid question, but as far as I know, they're not going anywhere if they aren't freed.

Comment: Each `new` must be followed by `delete`, or you get a leak. What you showed doesn't change this.

Comment: `Does instantiating classes without handles like this cause memory leaks in C++ ?` Yes. `Do they get deallocated after the method's definition goes out of scope ?` No. If __you__ don't `delete` them, they're not going to be free'd.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not really. A placement new does not necessarily leak. Also if the object has overridden the new operator and handles it with a garbage collector it also does not leak.

Comment: @NoleKsum Yes, but OP doesn't need to know this. When they eventually study placement-new, they will be told that it's an exception from this rule.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677812/is-there-a-reason-to-call-delete-in-c-when-a-program-is-exiting-anyway

Comment: In modern C++ you (almost) never call `new`. If you want an automatic stack variable, just declare it (and initialize it): `Someclass sc;`. If you want a dynamic variable you use `std::unique_ptr<Someclass>`: (`auto scP = std::make_unique<Someclass>()`).

Comment: Also note that new/delete may not even be necessary. And you should look for other solutions before typing new/delete. Like storing objects in std::vector.  If you need dynamic memory allocation use std:::unique_ptr/std::make_unique. Those pointers will automatically be deleted when they go out of scope.

Comment: @alfC "Modern C++" does not exist. It is a buzzword that keeps being flaunted around by snub types. Up to the latest standard C++23 the operator `new` is an integral part of the C++ language, period. All the rest is 100% personal preference.

Comment: @NoleKsum. There is a logic behind avoiding `new/delete`. This is enabled by `std::unique_ptr` which is also an integral part of the language. A part of the language that was not available before. Now call this whatever you want. “In a C++-that-was-not-available-before-but-is-available-now we typically not call new”. seems a mouthful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct. In default C++, every `new` call must be followed by a `delete`, otherwise it is a leak. However there are edge cases where `new` can be used without a `delete`.

One such case is with **placement new** where memory allocation is handled by yourself. Example:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char buffer[256];

    X* x1 = new (&buffer[0]) X{1,2};
    X* x2 = new (&buffer[8]) X{3,4};

    std::cout << "x1: " << x1->a << " " << x1->b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x2: " << x2->a << " " << x2->b << std::endl;

    // no leaks since the memory is released when `buffer` is 
    // deallocated. However it is good practice to call the 
    // destructor directly
    x1->~X();
    x2->~X();
}
```

Produces:

```
Program stdout
x1: 1 2
x2: 3 4
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/sEPWadcKh

Another case is when a class **overrides the operator new** as in this example:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

static char buffer[32768];
static char* ptr = &buffer[0];

struct X {
    int a;
    int b;
    void* operator new(size_t size) {
        void* p = ptr;
        ptr += size;
        return p;
    }
    void operator delete(void*) {
        // no need to do anything
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    X* x1 = new X{1,2};
    X* x2 = new X{3,4};

    std::cout << "x1: " << x1->a << " " << x1->b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "xs: " << x2->a << " " << x2->b << std::endl;

    // no leaks since the memory is released when `buffer` is 
    // deallocated. However it is good practice to call the 
    // destructor directly
    x1->~X();
    x2->~X();
}
```

Produces:

```
Program stdout
x1: 1 2
x2: 3 4
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/jc4r9qbxh

Yet another case is when you use `new` with **smart pointers** like in the case below

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>

struct X {
    X(int a_, int b_ ) : a(a_), b(b_){
        std::cout << "Constructor " << this << std::endl;
    }
    ~X() {
        std::cout << "Destructor " << this << std::endl;
    }
    int a;
    int b;
    int count = 0;
};

void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(X* x)
{
    ++x->count;
}

void intrusive_ptr_release(X* x)
{
    if (--x->count == 0)
        delete x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    boost::intrusive_ptr<X> x1 = new X{1,2};
    boost::intrusive_ptr<X> x2 = new X{3,4};

    std::cout << "x1: " << x1->a << " " << x1->b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x2: " << x2->a << " " << x2->b << std::endl;
}
```

Produces:

```
Constructor 0xb4b2b0
Constructor 0xb4c2e0
x1: 1 2
x2: 3 4
Destructor 0xb4c2e0
Destructor 0xb4b2b0
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/b7MTfazT9

So although `delete` is called on your behalf, **you** as in **the user** does not have to call `delete` yourself.

*Yet another* use case is when creating objects for frameworks that manage the lifetime of objects like [Qt](https://www.qt.io/).

So the answer is really YES, always call `delete` after `new` but there are plenty of cases in the industry where it is not really necessary.

Comment: is there such thing as “in default C++”? do you mean in “correct programs that don’t leak”?