# C++ Calling Functions in a COM DLL Possible Memory Leak

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, com

I created a C++ console app using VC++ 2017. It makes a number of calls over time to retrieve data from a 3rd party COM DLL. I use COM classes like CComSafeArray and CComVariant that manage their own freeing.

Over time I observe that the memory for my App steadily increases in Task Manager after each COM call.

I have used the CRT library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019) to try to detect memory leaks but it indicates I have none.

My question(s) is/are:

1. Does COM in general do it's own memory management that the CRT
   library cannot detect but is tied to my process?
2. If #1 is the case, are there tools available to detect COM memory
   leaks?
3. If #1 is the case, is there a way to garbage collect COM memory?

Thanks for your consideration.

**Edit 4-19-2019**
I have found out that the COM Dll returns VARIANT's and BSTR's for function call results. I am assigning them variously to _variant_t and _bstr_t as applicable to provide automatic cleanup (theoretically).
For example.

```
_variant_t v = GetSomeVariant();
_bstr_t b = GetSomeString();
```

The DLL does not use CoTaskMemAlloc but it does use SysAllocString to generate the BSTRs.

Comment: Observing memory increase through Task Manager is not really a reliable way to tell memory increasing. When you `delete/delete[]/free/etc` memory then usually it does not go straight back to the OS. It is reserved for later use.

Comment: Consider looking at the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421491/does-calling-free-or-delete-ever-release-memory-back-to-the-system)

Comment: Well, if this a modern app then heavy leaks of COM object shouldn't be surprising as MS mostly abandoned weak concept of object lifetime management through reference counting that has been previously used in COM. So instead of tracking COM memory leaks you should probably focus on making your app restart properly after getting killed because of resource exhaust.

Comment: @VTT: I'd downvote that if I could downvote comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_bstr_t b = GetSomeString();`

Presumably, that is `BSTR GetSomeString();`. Which to the compiler means`wchar_t* GetSomeString` ; `BSTR` tells you that it uses COM semantics but the compiler doesn't know that. And those semantics are that you call `SysFreeString`.

`_bstr_t::_bstr_t( wchar_t* str )` **copies** `str`. Yes, `_bstr_t::~_bstr_t` will then call `SysFreeString`, but it does so on the copy. You needed to call `SysFreeString` on the `BSTR GetSomeString();`.

The solution is `_bstr_t::_bstr_t( BSTR bstr , bool fCopy )` with `fCopy=false`. Per MSDN:

> This constructor is used by wrapper functions in the type library
>   headers to encapsulate and take ownership of a BSTR that is returned
>   by an interface method.

For `VARIANT`, see `_variant_t::_variant_t(VARIANT& varSrc, bool fCopy);`. Same idea.

Comment: I am willing to accept this answer because it makes sense. However, I have found out that this COM dll leaks serious memory without my pulling any data from it. It opens and closes file system files but seems to not to clean up after itself. So I cannot say for sure that this answer fixes my problem. However, I did adopt the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

COM does not use any automated garbage collection; everything has to be accounted for although there are helper classes available that take care of reference counting.

The convention in COM is that, if the called method allocates some memory then the caller has to free it with `CoTaskMemFree`. You may want to check your code for the DLL methods that you call and if they return anything in a buffer that was allocated by the DLL then you'll need to free that buffer by calling `CoTaskMemFree`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/memory-allocation-in-com

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/memory-management-rules

Comment: I amended my question (edit noted) to provide some insight about what the COM dll returns and how I assign return values.