# Using malloc to allocate memory for my Card deck in C?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to get to allocate a specific number of memory with `malloc`, however when I run my program it gives some random letter output, and I can't see whats the matter with it. This is the first time I experiment with `malloc`, so hope you can understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ACE 1
#define CardSize 52

void count();

int main()
{
    count();
    return 0;

}
void count() {
    int *cards;
    int i;
    cards = (int *)malloc(CardSize*sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", cards[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Basically it should print out 1-13 in my array of cards[52] the cards, 4 different times. I don't understand why it won't do this, hope someone could help me out.

Comment: C doesn't do magic. Where's your code that initializes that array you've allocated?

Comment: You have two nested loops with the same control variable, which is a recipe for disaster. And your indices in the inner loop starts at 1 (it should start at 0) and it iterates once too many (14 instead of 13 passes).

Comment: when calling `malloc()` (and calloc() and realloc())  in C, do not cast the returned value.  The returned value is already a `void*` so can be assigned to any other variable.  Casting just clutters the code, makes debug and/or maintenance harder.   When calling `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically it should print out 1-13 in my array of cards[52] the cards,
>   4 different times. I don't understand why it won't do this

In for loop you have only used one control variable `i`. And for printing 1-13 you have to assign values , you haven't assign anywhere in code.
Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ACE 1
#define CardSize 52

void count();

int main()
{
    count();
    return 0;

}
void count() {
    int *cards;
    int i,j;
    cards = malloc(CardSize*sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
             cards[i*13+j]=j+1;
            printf("%d ", cards[i*13+j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
free(cards);
}
```

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
>             for (j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
>                   cards[i*13+j]=j+1;
>                 printf("%d ", cards[i*13+j]);
>             }
> ```

step 1: Here first for loop initialize `i=0`

step 2: second for loop initialize `j=0`

step 3: cards[i*13+j]=j+1; will execute.here `j=0` and `i=0` so cards[0]=1 will be assigned

step 4: `printf` will print value of `cards[i*13+j]` here `j=0` so value       of cards[0] will be printed. again loop will go to step 2 and increment j.
upto 1-13 will be printed.

step 5: Again first for loop will be started and again 1-13 will be printed and so on until first for loop get finished.

Note: [Do not cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and I suggest use `free()` after dynamic memory allocation to [free memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc).

You can also use single loop instead of double loop

```
for (i = 0; i < CardSize; i++) {
             cards[i]=(i%13)+1;
            printf("%d ", cards[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You allocate memory to your pointer , but you never *initialize* it . And you print it , therefore , doesn't give you intended output .

You can modify loop as follows -

```
    while(i<52){                      // first initialize i=0
        j=1;                          // set j to 1 in each iteration
        while(j<14){                  // iterate for 14 times
             cards[i]=j;              // initialize chards
             printf("%d", cards[i]);
             j++;
             i++;
        }
       printf("\n");
    }
```

[Output](https://ideone.com/rrPnXJ)

**Note**-

**1.** You should check the return of `malloc` ,also `free` the allocated memory.

**2.** Cast in `malloc` statement is *redundant and unnecessary* .

Answer (score 1):

You have two loops, so you need two control variables, and you have to calculate the index for the linearized array.

```
void count() {
    int *cards;
    cards = (int *)malloc(CardSize*sizeof(int));
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // first loop with control varible i
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) { // second loop with control varible j
            int arrI = i*13+j; // linearized index 
             cards[arrI]= /* what ever */;
            printf("%d\n", cards[arrI]);
        }

    }
    free(cards);
}
```