# Why give "stop working" error message when work with structure in c?

Tags: c

I need to understand why give this error message "stop working". Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char *title;
};

int main()
{
    struct student *st;
    st->id = 23;
    //st->name = "shaib";
    st->title = "title";

    printf ("%d", st->id);
    printf ("%s", st->title);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You define a pointer but it is not init, so is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can create a space in heap memory using [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) function.

```
int main()
{
    struct student *st = malloc(sizeof(struct student));

    if ( st != NULL)
    { 
       st->id = 23;
       ..
    }
    else
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "No space for variable\n");
    }

    free(st);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, each time you allocate memory with `malloc` you are responsible for `free`ing it. Otherwise you have [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc)

Second problem is that

```
 st->name = "shaib";
```

is not the way you fill an array with a C-String.

You can achieve it with:

```
 strcpy(st->name, "shaib");
```

Comment: `st->title` is declared as `char *title;`, so st->title = "title" is appropriate, and using strcpy is not appropriate unless you first  malloc some space for the pointer.

Comment: @FredK oooops, I confound it with `name[20]` Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So, you need to allocate some memory for your new struct:

1) Add a #include  in order to...

2) Replace the struct declaration for a malloc()

Tip: use a better format for your print outputs with \t and \n

Here's the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char *title;
};

int main()
{
    struct student *st = malloc(sizeof (struct student));
    st->id = 23;
    //st->name = "shaib";
    st->title = "title";

    printf ("%d\t", st->id);
    printf ("%s\n", st->title);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a pointer to the student structure, but you're not setting it to point to anything.

You'll need to allocate memory for st (the student structure) before you can use it.

Comment: Thanks. If I create non-pointer object it works fine, but why ? I did not understand.

Comment: Hi @coder_hasib If you create a local variable then it will be created on the stack and available to use within the current scope (i.e. the stack takes care of it for you). If you decide to dynamically allocate the memory on the heap for the structure (using malloc) then you need to keep a pointer to that memory location so that you can deference it when necessary (access it's value).

Answer (score 2):

You are not allocating memory for `st`.

You can do it like this: `st = malloc(sizeof (student));`