# How should I free a malloc variable when it has been assigned to another variable as well? (C Language)

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

Sorry if this has been asked already.

I have this program:

```
int main()
{
  int *X = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
  *X = 10; 
  int *Y = X;
  free(Y);

  return 0;
}
```

I don't know if the code is correct already or not. Do I still need to call `free(X)` as I have called `malloc()` for `X`? Do I need to call `malloc()` for `Y` as well, or is `Y` fine as it is?

Comment: For every `malloc` should be only one `free`. The code is correct in this sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not correct because required header `stdlib.h` is not included and the result of `malloc()` is not checked. Also casting results of `malloc()` in C is [discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Correct code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int *X = malloc(sizeof(int));
  if (X == NULL) return 1;
  *X = 10;
  int *Y = X;
  free(Y);

  return 0;
}
```

You don't need and mustn't call `free(X);` because `X` is pointing at the same point as `Y` and the memory is already freed by `free(Y);`.

You need to call `malloc()` for `Y` if you want `Y` point at different (new) thing than `X`. In this case freeing both what are pointed at by `X` and `Y` is recommended.
(freeing will satisfy checkers like Valgrind, but in modern OS you don't have to free things at end of program execution because the OS will free up all memories used in your process. For more information, see [c - What REALLY happens when you don't free after malloc? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc))

Comment: Maybe nitpicking, but skipping the check of return value does not make the code incorrect. It just makes it unsafe and bad. :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to care about variables. You only need to care about allocated memory blocks.

Your code is fine (except for missing headers)
You allocate a block and free the same block again. That's it.

If you add another `malloc` for `Y` you will cause a memory leak when you assign valu of `X`. If you add `free(X)` you free the same block twice which is illegal.

Note: You must be aware that after `free(Y)` you are not allowed to access `*X` as the memory does not belong to you anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I free a malloc variable when it has been assigned to
> another variable as well? (C Language)

You need not to free the declared variables (pointers) `X` and `Y`. They have automatic storage duration and will be freed automatically by the compiler when the control exits the scope where the variables are declared.

What you need is to free the dynamically allocated memory in this declaration

```
int *X = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

The memory was allocated one time and shall be freed also one time independent on how many pointers point to the allocated memory.

After this declaration

```
int *Y = X;
```

two pointers, `X` and `Y`, point now to the allocated memory.

To free the allocated memory you can use either of the pointers as for example

```
free( X );
```

or

```
free( Y );
```

After such a call the both pointers are dangling pointers. Usually it is a good idea to set such pointers to `NULL`.

```
X = NULL;
Y = NULL;
```