# free variable when use malloc in c

Tags: c, malloc, free

```
char **loadValues()
{
    char **toReturn;
    int i;
    toReturn = malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        toReturn[i] = malloc(25);              //Change the size as per your need
        strncpy(toReturn[i], "string", i + 1); //Something to copy
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

I copied above part of the code. In it, the "toReturn" variable is initialized by using `malloc`. Don't we have to "free" this "toReturn" variable?

Don't we have to free these variables when we return them in C. I still couldn't find a clear answer and I can't find a way to free it when I return it. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: You don't have to use `free()` if you are on modern OS and don't use `loadValues()` too many times. [c - What REALLY happens when you don't free after malloc? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc) Another condition is that you don't have to satisfy checkers like Valgrind.

Comment: Freeing what to return is a bad idea because returning means it will be used later and using freed buffer is illegal.

Comment: That's like giving your previous phone number to someone asking for your number

Comment: Aside: a hidden danger. Function `strncpy()` does not supply a null terminator if it reaches the `count` limit, and `malloc()` does not initialise the memory it gives. So no terminator.

Comment: Thank you all. I learned more things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your question is: how does the function that calls `loadValues` and receives the pointer it returns, can free the loaded values.

If we leave `loadValues` as it is now, the best solution is to create another function, called `freeValues` and call it when we are done with the values:

```
void freeValues(char **values)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        free(values[i]);
    }
    free(values);
}
```

Then you can do something like this in your main program:

```
char **values = loadValues();
// ... use values for something
freeValues(values);
```

Another option, is to allocate toReturn using a single call to `malloc`, in which case it can be freed simply by calling to `free`.

Comment: Aside: In the spirit of `freeNULL)` being OK, suggest tolerating `freeValues(NULL)`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot free the allocated memory inside the function and return that data so that it can be used outside the function. But you still can `free()` the memory outside the function.

Comment: That is correct, congratulations for you first answer, and your first upvote.

Answer (score 2):

> *Don't we have to "free" this "toReturn" variable?*

Yes, eventually you'd want to free the memory after you're done with it.

> *I still couldn't find clear answer and I can't find a way to free it when I return it. Can someone explain it to me?*

When you use the function you assign it to a new pointer, you can use this pointer, not only to access the memory block you returned, but also to free it, example:

```
int main()
{
    char** values = loadValues();
    
    // do something with values

    // don't need them anymore
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        free(values[i]);
    }
    free(values);
}
```

---

Note that `strncpy(toReturn[i], "string", i + 1);` is likely not what you want, in each iteration you are copying only from 1 to 5 characters respectively, not the entire string, and more importantly, not the null terminator.

The third argument of `strncpy` should be the length of `"string"` plus 1 more byte for the null terminator, so `7` in this case. Alternatively, if want to copy only part of ther string, you have to null-terminate it yourself.

If the goal is to copy the entire string, you can let the compiler do that for you:

```
//...
toReturn = malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    toReturn[i] = strdup("string");  // duplicate string and store it in toReturn[i]
}
//...
```

Of course you still need to free it yourself like in the first situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I got it and learn more things.