# Dynamic Memory Allocation Of an Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been trying to write a simple code wherein the array is allocated dynamically. Every time I specify the side of the array as n(suppose 4) and proceed to type the given input, it takes exactly n+1(5 in this case) inputs from me but as the output, it prints n(4) elements.

Here's the main function I wrote:

```
int main() {
    int *arr, n;
    scanf("%d", &n); //n is the size
    arr = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%d ", &arr[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0 ; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I've also tried doing the code by initializing i in the first loop as 1, and in that way it takes exactly n inputs but it gives a weird output, something like this:

```
7953616 1 2 3
```

Comment: `scanf("%d ", &arr[i]);` --> `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);`.  Drop space.  Certainly a dupe someplace.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, it does give the correct output now but why is that space mattering so much?

Comment: `" "` consumes 0 or more white-spaces.  So it does not return until seeing a following non-white-space to know all white-space consumed.

Comment: [C FAQ: Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) In particular [12.17](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica oh I understand now, thank you.

Comment: @Schwern Thank you, [12.17](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html) was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in those two lines

```
    scanf("%d ", &arr[i]);
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
```

you have `%d`  instead of `%d`

also you need to use `free()` from `stdlib` library as after you finish using the pointer you need to free the memory in order to reuse it again [otherwise this will happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc#:%7E:text=Even%20if%20you%20fail%20to,the%20program%20is%20finished%20running.)

final code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
 int *arr, n;
 scanf("%d", &n); //n is the size
 arr = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
 scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
 for(int i=0 ; i<n; i++) 
 printf("%d", arr[i]);
 free(arr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. @Saifeddine Ben Salem