# Stack VS Heap, what goes where here?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, storage-duration

So I started playing around with C and having a lot of fun thus far.

There are however a couple of things I can not wrap my head around.

I know that this will end up on the stack

```
int i = 0;
```

I know this will reserve space for an integer on the heap and return the adress

```
int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

However. If i do this

```
int i_one = 1, i_two = 2;
int *arr = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
arr[0] = i_one;
arr[1] = i_two;
```

i_one and two are stack allocated while arr is on the heap. Does this mean that arr will copy the values of i_one and two on to the heap or will it simply hold 2 references to variables on the stack. Im assuming its a variant of alt one considering (if I'm not misstaken) my stack allocated ints will be freed as soon as I exit this function.

So to summarize, when creating a dynamically allocated array using calloc. Do the entries in the array need to be pointers / heap allocated as well? In my head that would not make sense because then wouldnt i create an array of int pointers instead? And yes I know the size of a pointer is the same as an int so the example is a bit stupid but you get the point.

Thank you

Comment: int and pointer isn't the same size (that's depend on the system) :)  int is 4 bytes while pointer is word size (4/8 bytes in our life time :) )

Comment: Really? I thought a pointer was always the same size in bytes as an integer be that 4 or 8 bytes depending on os.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment operator is designed to assign a value stored in one object to another object.

So in these assignment statements

```
arr[0] = i_one;
arr[1] = i_two;
```

values stored in the variables `i_one` and `i_two` are copied into the memory occupied by the array elements `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`. Now if you will change for example the value stored in the variable `i_one` then the value stored in `arr[0]` will not be changed.

If you want to store references to objects `i_one` and `i_two` in the heap then you should write

```
int **arr = calloc(2, sizeof(int *));
arr[0] = &i_one;
arr[1] = &i_two;
```

Now you can change for example the value stored in `i_one` by means of the array element `arr[0]` the following way

```
*arr[0] = 10;
```

Comment: I think in my case it would be easier to store that actual values since I dont need them to be pointers and once created i will not need to modify them (at least not the original values). But that means that when I do

arr[0] = i_one;
arr[1] = i_two;

Then copies of i_one and two live on the heap correct? and once I do free(arr). Then those copies are removed from the heap as well I assume? Unlike the example with an array of pointers.

Comment: @JohanFredin If you will free the memory pointed to by the pointer arr then values stored in the dynamically allocated array will not be acceptable. But the values stored in i_one and i_two will be alive.

Answer (score 2):

You say that with

```
int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

> this will end up on the heap

Actually, things aren't quite as simple as that...

If the variable `i` is a local variable inside a function, then the space for the *variable itself* will be located in "automatic storage", i.e. the stack. But the pointer returned by `malloc` will point to the heap.

Comment: and would be access-able from every point in the program so if you will return `i` the heap address will be sent back

Comment: @AsafItach Yes, the value of `i` will be copied and returned, and that value is the location of (the first byte of) the heap-allocated memory. And the life-time of heap-allocated memory is until the pointer returned by `malloc` is passed to `free`.

Comment: correct! i presume you familiar with this post.. (even tho i'm always use free each time i malloc things) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the correction, I was oversimplifying it. Yes, malloc will create space for an int on the heap and i will hold the address to it and I would have to keep track of it and free it when no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the memory map by printing all relevant types or symbols to my knowledge (originally i used static libraries, dynamic loading, and run-time loading but it can be a bit confusing).

I also crated two **"heap variables"** and print their address and the local pointer which contain their address

->->-> so you can see the local pointer is in the stack but their **actual** address is at the beginning of the heap. and that's why you can use this allocated variables outside the stack frame - your local pointer get deleted but the address is stayed at the heap.

this is my program output:

```
 ------------------COMMAND-LINE------------------
 |*envp--------------------->           140737488347777|
 |*argv--------------------->           140737488347751|
 
 |envp--------------------->            140737488346896|
 |argv--------------------->            140737488346864|
 
 
 ------------------STACK------------------
 |str1--------------------->            140737488346090|
 |alloc_second address----->            140737488346048|
 |alloc_first address------>            140737488346040|
 |const_local_second ------>            140737488346032|
 |const_local_first-------->            140737488346024|
 |argc--------------------->            140737488346012|
 ------------------FUNC-STACK-FRAME------------------
 |fun_var_const------------>            140737488345956|
 |fun_var_second----------->            140737488345952|
 |fun_var------------------>            140737488345948|
 
 
 ------------------HEAP------------------
 
 ------------------------MMS---------------------------------------
 |strlen(library func)----->            140737353401952|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 |alloc_second------------->                4215488|
 |alloc_first-------------->                4215456|
 
 
 ------------------BSS------------------
 |global_const = 0 -------->                4210812|
 |global_int_first--------->                4210808|
 |global_double_first------>                4210800|
 |static_int_first--------->                4210796|
 |global_int_const--------->                4202504|
 
 |------------------DATA------------------
 |static_int_second-------->                4210784|
 |global_double_second----->                4210776|
 ------------------DATA - READ ONLY------------------
 |const_static_int_second-->                4204408|
 |const_static_int_first--->                4204412|
 |string literal----------->                4202700|
 
 
 ------------------TEXT------------------
 |extern function --------->                4200215|
 |function (define after)-->                4200181|
 |main -------------------->                4199038|
 |static function --------->                4198870|
 
 -----------------------BOTTOM LINE------------------
```