# Why i am not able to assign a struct node pointer with allocated memory to a struct node pointer with previous value of null for making a linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

Created a struct node pointer and initialized it with null and then passed it to create a linked list, it works if we initialized the head pointer with malloc but dont work this way can anyone say where i am wrong ??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int i;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *ptr;
};

void create(struct node *head, int n)
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct node *p = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        scanf("%d", &p->data);
        if (head == NULL)
            head = p;
        else
        {
            head->ptr = p;
        }
    }
}
void display(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *p = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty Linked List");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d", head->data);
            p = p->ptr;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    create(head, n);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?  Where is `struct node` defined?

Comment: @MrMischievousX  This if (head->ptr == NULL)
            head->data = p->data;
        else
        {
            head->ptr = p;
        } does not make a sense and produces a memory leak.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow can you correct me in this ?

Comment: What is the desired output for, for example, input `3 1 2 3`?

Comment: @MikeCAT 1 2 3 should be output

Answer (score 0):

- The argument `head` is *a copy of* what is passed, so modification of that won't affect what is passed in the caller. You should pass *pointers of* what should be modified to have functions modify caller's local things.
- You have to initialize `p->ptr` not to cause *undefined behavior* by using (indeterminate) value of buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized.
- You should print `p->data`, not `head->data`, in the function `display()`.
- Casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int i;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *ptr;
};

void create(struct node **head, int n) /* receive pointer */
{
    /* go to the end of list */
    while (*head != NULL)
    {
        head = &(*head)->ptr;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); /* don't cast results of malloc() */
        scanf("%d", &p->data);
        p->ptr = NULL; /* initialize p->ptr */
        *head = p; /* dereference the pointer to update list */
        head = &p->ptr; /* go to the next place to append node */
    }
}
void display(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *p = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty Linked List");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d", p->data); /* output correct thing */
            p = p->ptr;
            if (p != NULL) putchar(' '); /* add space for proper output */
        }
    }
}

int main(void) /* use standard signature */
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    create(&head, n); /* pass pointer */
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Other non-critical points:

- You should check results of `scanf()` to check if it successfully read desired things.
- You should check results of `malloc()` to check if allocation succeeded and to avoid dereferencing `NULL`.
- Making loop counter `i` global doesn't make sense.
- The nodes are not freed. [This won't be a problem on modern OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc), but memory checkers like Valgrind may warn about that.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving problem and for other valuable resources

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is a bad idea to declare the global variable `i`

```
int i;
```

You should declare variable in minimal scopes where they are used.

Your function `create` does not make a sense.

```
void create(struct node *head, int n)
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct node *p = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        scanf("%d", &p->data);
        if (head == NULL)
            head = p;
        else
        {
            head->ptr = p;
        }
    }
}
```

For starters as the pointer to the head node is passed by value to the function then the function deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer. Changing the copy within the function as for example in this statement

```
head = p;
```

does not influence on the original pointer in main. It will stay unchanged.

Also there are numerous memory leaks because addresses of the allocated memory for nodes in the loop are being lost because in this statement

```
head->ptr = p;
```

they are being overwritten.

The function should do only one thing: add a new node with the specified value to the list. The for loop should be moved in the caller of the function.

The function can look the following way

```
int create( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *p = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = p != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        p->data = data;
        p->ptr = *head;
        *head = p;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And in main the function can be called for example the following way

```
struct node *head = NULL;
int n;
scanf( "%d", &n );

int success = 1;

for ( int i = 0; success && i < n; i++ )
{
    int data;
    scanf( "%d", &data );    
    success = create( &head, data );
}
```

Pay attention to that in the function display you are outputting a value stored in the head node

```
printf("%d", head->data);
```

you have to write

```
printf("%d", p->data);
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how new nodes can be added to the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *ptr;
};

int create( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *p = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = p != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        p->data = data;
        p->ptr = *head;
        *head = p;
    }

    return success;
}

FILE * display( const struct node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->ptr )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    
    size_t n = 0;
    
    printf( "Enter the number of nodes you want to add to the list: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &n );
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    
    int success = 1;
    for ( size_t i = 0; success && i < n; i++ )
    {
        success = create( &head, rand() % ( int )( 2 * n ) );
    }
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the number of nodes you want to add to the list: 10
11 -> 16 -> 10 -> 18 -> 9 -> 0 -> 8 -> 1 -> 3 -> 18 -> null
```

Comment: Your code will create a list `3 2 1`, not `1 2 3` as desired, from an input `3 1 2 3`. (It will be printed as `333` unless you fix the `display()` function)

Comment: @MikeCAT The input is desired by whom? By you? Why can not you  for example write 3 3 2 1?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int i;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *ptr;
};

void create(struct node *head, int n)
{
    struct node *p = head;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &p->data);
        if(i<n-1)
        {
            struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->ptr=NULL;
            p->ptr=temp;
            p=temp;
        }
    }
}
void display(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *p = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty Linked List");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d", p->data);
            p = p->ptr;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct node *head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->ptr = NULL;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    create(head, n);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```