# Free dynamically alloted memory to struct array containing pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, memory-leaks

I have three files

```
struct.h  struct.c main.c
```

struct.h contains declaration of structs and some functions
struct.c contains global variable `bglobal` an instance of `struct b` and function implementations which use `bglobal`. It includes .h file
main.c call some of the functions declared in struct.h. It also includes .h file
struct.h contains two struct

```
struct a{
int *s
}
struct b{
struct a* arr
}
void init();
void more();
```

struct.c file

```
#include"struct.h"
struct b bglobal;
void init(){
   bglobal.arr = malloc(sizeof(struct a)*5);
}
void more(){
   *bglobal.arr[0].name = 'I';
}
```

main.c file

```
#include "main.h"
int main(){
init();
more();
}
```

I want that at end of program memory allocated to `bglobal.arr` get freed up.
Using valgrind it says some bytes still reachable.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Do reversed steps of the allocation or [just exit your program and have the OS free the memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc).

Comment: did you try `free(bglobal.arr)`?

Comment: there is no such thing as "memory allocated to bglobal.arr" by the way. There is just memory allocated.

Comment: free(bglobal.arr) works but I cant call it from main.c as bglobal is declared in struct.c

Comment: @MikeCAT I can do reverse but ho to do at the end of program. I mean is there something like destructor in c.

Comment: Register an exit handler in `init()` that frees the allocated memory when the program exits. Or provide an uninit() function that the client code can call themselves to free the resources.

Comment: I can't add anything to struct.h. Can u give me some link about exit handler.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit

Comment: where should I register this . If I do in main.c I cant free bglobal as it is declared in struct.c. There is no main in struct.c

Comment: You can call `atexit` from your `init` function.

Comment: Although it is cleaner to free everything that was allocated, it is usually only the *chronic* memory leaks that cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a cleanup function to struct.c to free the memory.  And since you can't reference that function from outside the module, you can set it up with `atexit` from `init` to be called when the program exits.

```
static void cleanup() {
    free(bglobal.arr);
}

void init(){
   bglobal.arr = malloc(sizeof(struct a)*5);
   atexit(cleanup);
}
```

Comment: Given OP's limitation, this is good  - aside from the side issue of the mis-type in `sizeof(struct a)`.  I'd also `free(bglobal.arr);` --> `free(bglobal.arr); bglobal.arr = 0;` to cope with other potential `atexit()` using `bglobal.arr`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want that at end of program memory allocated to bglobal.arr get freed up.

Add a complement function to `init()`

```
int main(){
  init();
  // do stuff
  uninit();  // this functions frees resources.
}
```

If `struct.h` does not allow improvement, make a local function in main.c.

```
void uninit(void) {
  extern struct b bglobal; // Take advantage that bglobal is not static
  free(bgolbal.arr);
}
```

---

`bgolbal.arr = malloc(sizeof(struct b)*5);` allocates to the wrong type. `.arr` is a `struct a*`.  Allocate to the referenced object instead as it is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
bgolbal.arr = malloc(sizeof *bgolbal.arr * 5);
```

Comment: I cant add anything to str.h. So this method will not work as uninit() will be implemented in str.c but cant be referenced in main.c.

Comment: @aquib nawaz  In `main.c` , `void uninit(void) { extern struct b bglobal; free(bgolbal.arr); }`.  Take advantage that `bglobal` is not `static`. or better fight the questionable requirement "I can't add anything to struct.h." as `struct.c` is poorly written

Comment: This is annoying but this is assignment.

Comment: @aquib nawaz, go with `atexit()` approach then.  As your coding experience grows, you will see that requirements are negotiable.  Do not get stuck is a weak design.