# Why is salary not displaying in the file in following code?

Tags: c, string, structure, file-handling

Everything else is displaying in file as it is supposed to be other than the salary of the bank employee.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct data {
    char ide[50], name[50], bname[50], brname[50], con[10], sal[30];
};

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of employees: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct data d[n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("Enter data of employee %d\n", i);
        printf("1) ID: ");
        scanf("%s", d[i].ide);
        printf("2) NAME: ");
        scanf("%s", d[i].name);
        printf("3) SALARY: ");
        scanf("%s", d[i].sal);
        printf("4) CONTACT: ");
        scanf("%s", d[i].con);
        printf("5) BANK NAME: ");
        scanf("%s", d[i].bname);
        printf("6) BRANCH NAME: ");
        scanf("%s", d[i].brname);
    }
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("dbms.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "1) ID: %s\n2) NAME: %s\n3) SALARY: %s\n4) CONTACT: %s\n5) BANK NAME: %s\n6) BRANCH NAME: %s\n",
                d[i].ide, d[i].name, d[i].sal, d[i].con, d[i].bname, d[i].brname);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Array indices are 0..n-1  (not 1..n like your loops assume).

Comment: Please do not provide an external link instead of code. Code should be posted directly in questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array indice in C starts from 0, not 1, and what to specify for array declaration is not the maximum index but the number of elements.

Therefore, your loop `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` with the array `struct data d[n];` will lead to out-of-range access.

You should loop from `0` to `n-1` instead of `1` to `n` like this:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Also note that VLA (variable-length array) like `struct data d[n];` may not work with large data size because it may be allocated on the stack with limited size. You should allocate memory on the heap via `malloc()` instead like this:

```c
struct data *d = malloc(sizeof(*d) * n);
if (d == NULL) {
    /* allocateion failed */
    exit(1);
}
```

You should add `#include <stdlib.h>` to use `malloc()` (and `exit()`).
Checkers may say that you should use `free()` to deallocate allocated memory after use, but [it may not be required in the real world just before end of program execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc-before-program-termination).