# C code not throwing error for initializing extra string character than it is supposed to be

Tags: c, malloc

I was running this code to expect an error but to my surprise, it didn't. Even if I initialize a string*(5 bytes)* that is greater than what was allocated using **malloc** (*4bytes).*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

        char * name = malloc(4);
        name = "hello";
        
        printf("%s\n",name);
        return 0;


}
```

This is the output

```
$ sample.c
$ ./a.out
hello
```

What might be the underlying details behind this  and also why it is not showing *segmentation fault* as I didn't free the memory?

Comment: There is no undefined behaviour - you simply overwrite the pointer with another. The `=` does not copy a string. But anyway, even if you had written past the end of the buffer,  failure is not guaranteed. Aside: the string takes 6 bytes not 5.

Comment: I wonder whether you tried to `free` the buffer before `return`.

Comment: @AGNGazer yes I used `free(name)` it executed hello, at last, it showed me `Aborted (core dumped)`.

Comment: The very basic nature of *undefined behaviour* is that it is not defined what will happen. Especially it is not required to trigger some error message. The resulting behaviour may as well look like everything was fine. That is the worst class of errors. It may seem to work fine until it finally bites you when you don't expect it.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you now I understood what undefined error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement doesn't copy `hello` to `name`. It changes what `name` was originally pointing to:

```
name = "hello";
```

Now that `name` points to `hello`, we have lost all access to the original memory allocated with `malloc` and there is no way to `free` it.

There's no undefined behaviour here, but even if there was, the compiler is not required to warn you about it.

---

*"Re: why it is not showing segmentation fault as I didn't free the memory?"*

---

Memory leaks do not raise a segmentation violation signal. It's your job, as a programmer, to manage memory, and avoid any leaks.

---

"*Re: I used free(name) it executed hello, at last, it showed me Aborted (core dumped)."*

---

That's because you're trying to `free` memory that wasn't allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, `aligned_alloc`, or `realloc`. (Why give something that belongs to the data segment or the stack to the heap?)

Only call `free` with pointers as they are returned by `malloc`, `calloc`, `aligned_alloc`, or `realloc`.

*Aside:* A string in `C` is an array of null-terminated bytes. The string `"hello"` contains 6 bytes, not 5.

Comment: Ohh k , I'll correct it.

Comment: What will happen if i avoid leaks and does not free my memory ? , sorry for asking this silly questions

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory. How are memory leaks likely when you ```free``` all memory you dynamically allocated on the heap?

Comment: what i am saying is what will happen if i don't free heap memory ?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/654754/20017547