# Allocating a 2D array of structures

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct

I want to allocate a 2D array of my custom type "cell", which is a structure. However, I am doing something wrong, see my code below. Could you please tell me where my mistake is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  int variable_1;
  int variable_2;
  int variable_3;
} cell;


void initialiseArray(unsigned long rows, unsigned long columns, cell array[rows][columns])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i = i + 1)
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j = j + 1)
    {
      array[i][j].variable_1 = 0;
      array[i][j].variable_2 = 0;
      array[i][j].variable_3 = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
  unsigned long rows = 200;
  unsigned long columns = 250;
  cell* array[rows];
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < rows; i = i + 1)
    array[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(cell));


  if (array == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error in ""main"": Memory could not be allocated.\n");
    return 3;
  }

  initialiseArray(rows, columns, array);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error `array == NULL` check doesn't make sense as it's a stack allocated variable.  You should check if `array[i]` is NULL though.

Comment: It's weird that you use a vla (i.e. stack allocated) for the row pointers but dynamically (heap) the columns.  Do one or the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cell* array[rows];` is a variable length array (VLA) that is allocated on the stack; each row is allocated on the heap with `array[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(cell));`.

I suggest you either allocate the `array` on the stack or heap:

1. Stack:

```
    cell array[rows][columns];
    initialiseArray(rows, columns, array);
```

You cannot initilaize VLAs, btw, so you still need `initialiseArray()` (or use `memset()`).  On Linux the default stack size is 8 MB, and if you try to use more than that your program will probably segfault.

2. Heap:

```
    cell (*array)[rows][columns] = malloc(sizeof *array);
    initialiseArray(rows, columns, *array);
```

As @yano mentioned you can use `calloc()` to zero initialize your memory so you don't necessarily need to call `initialiseArray()`.  On Linux the limit is whatever amount of free physical memory + swap (say, 16 GB), and if you try to use more than available `malloc()` / `calloc()` will return NULL which you can easily handle.

Either is in fine in this case.  If `rows` and `columns` are only known at run-time prefer heap allocation.

Prefer passing variable instead of a type of `sizeof`.

While `i` and `j` are perfectly valid loop variables consider using `r` / `row` or `c` / `col` / `column` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/Tea3oEx53), you have a number of issues, some more serious that others.  The most egregious violation is the `array` argument of `initialiseArray`.  When you pass an array to a function as an argument, it *decays* to a pointer to the first element.  You have an array of `cell` pointer types, or `cell*` types.  So a pointer to this type is a `cell**` type, so that's what you should change the argument to:

```c
void initialiseArray(unsigned long rows, unsigned long columns, cell** array)
```

Additional warnings that you should fix:

1. Comparing `int` to `unsigned long` in `initialiseArray`
2. Checking `if (array == NULL)` makes no sense, it's an array in automatic storage, it will never be NULL.  Instead, you mean to check `if (array[i] == NULL)`, so move that check into the loop that's doing the `malloc`ing.

```c
void initialiseArray(unsigned long rows, unsigned long columns, cell** array)
{
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < rows; i = i + 1)
    for (unsigned long j = 0; j < columns; j = j + 1)
    {
      array[i][j].variable_1 = 0;
      array[i][j].variable_2 = 0;
      array[i][j].variable_3 = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned long rows = 200;
  unsigned long columns = 250;
  cell* array[rows];
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < rows; i = i + 1)
  {
    array[i] = calloc(sizeof(cell), columns);
    if (array[i] == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in ""main"": Memory could not be allocated.\n");
        return 3;
    }
  }

  initialiseArray(rows, columns, array);

  return 0;
}
```

But since you're initializing your memory to 0, there's really no need for the `initialiseArray` function at all, simply allocate with [`calloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc):

```c
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < rows; i = i + 1)
{
  array[i] = calloc(sizeof(cell), columns);
  if (array[i] == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error in ""main"": Memory could not be allocated.\n");
    return 3;
  }
}
```

Now your memory is zeroized, no need to roll your own function.

Finally, don't forget to clean up your allocated memory [if you so choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc-before-program-termination)